# How to merge PART commits of branch A to branch B with egit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

There're two branches, branch-A and branch-B. And some commits in each branch, commit-a1, commit-a2, commit-b1 ...
How to ONLY merge commit-a2 from branch-A to branch-B USING EGIT?

Comment: If you only want an egit solution, why did you use the [tag:git] tag?

Comment: My "ONLY" is for "merge commit-a2", not for egit. Sorry for my ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest solution is to use `git cherry-pick`:

```
git checkout branch-B
git cherry-pick commit-a2
```

This makes a new commit on branch-B with the same changes as `commit-a2`.

Comment: I would have suggested about the same, but OP wanted an egit solution...

Comment: Egit doesn't have the function? Thanks all the same.

Comment: Cloud I merge all the commits after a2(a3,a4…) from branch-A to B? No use commit hash one by one. In other words, I wanna merge branch-A to B except commit-a1.

Comment: @youngzy I'm not familiar with Egit. I show the command-line version here because I know it best. It also shows the terminology that you can look for in Egit. To "merge" more than one commit from branch-A while skipping the first commit, you will have to use `git rebase` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll study the `rebase` command. By the way, the @ sign doesn't show the options? I rarely use it.